# Binding a single column to a Multiselect List

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a table called Service and within which there is a column called TSBNumber.  I am trying to display the value in the form of a multi-select in a view. I am confused by the DataText and Data Value Field for this, since this is a single field itself, the datatext and value fields are the same.

```
var tsbNumbersList = (from se in db.ServiceEntry
                                   join r in db.System1 on se.SystemID equals r.ID
                                   where se.Active == true && r.PlatformID == 1 && se.TSBNumber != null
                                   select se.TSBNumber).ToList().Distinct()
```

Should I just pass in the Collection, If I do so then in the dropdown in the view I see System.SelecListItem

```
   <div class="bodyContent">
            <span class="leftContent"><a id="qTipServiceTsbExportTsbSelection" href=''>
                @Html.Label("TSB Number")</a> </span><span class="rightContent">
                    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedTsbs, new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.TsbNumber, Model.SelectedTsbs),
                    new { id = "Tsblstbox", name = "listbox", @class = "chosen-select", multiple = "multiple", data_placeholder = "Click here to Select Tsb Number...", style = "width:90%;", tabindex = "4" }
                    )
                </span>
        </div>
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to both display and assign the values of `TSBNumber` to property `SelectedTsbs`?

Comment: The query returns the field, I would like this to be displayed in the multi-select dropdown.  WHen the user selects values from this dropdown, the indexes are stored in an array which is the selectedPTsbs. WHen users hit a button on this view, a controller action recieves the selected ptsIds

Comment: But is the value of `TSBNumber` the same as the values you store in the `SelectedTsbs` array (or does `ServiceEntry` contain an ID property that you want to store in `SelectedTsbs`)

Comment: Nope, selectedTsbs should send the values as is, i.e in the there are five rows and this column called TSBNumber has values 121,asdas,q231,1231,2131 - so these values will display in the drop down and  public string[] SelectedTsbs { get; set; } is string array which will send selected items back to the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the query to remove the `select` clause

```
var tsbNumbersList = (from se in db.ServiceEntry
  join r in db.System1 on se.SystemID equals r.ID
  where se.Active == true && r.PlatformID == 1 && se.TSBNumber != null
  select se).Distinct();
```

and create a `SelectList` based on the collection

```
ViewBag.TsbNumber = new SelectList(tsbNumbersList, "TSBNumber", "TSBNumber");
```

and in the view

```
 @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedTsbs, (SelectList)ViewBag.TsbNumber)
```

If the value of `string[] SelectedTsbs` is ["121", "q231"], then the 1st and 3rd options will be selected.

Comment: query must have a select clause, it throws out an error.

Comment: Oops - got mixed up with query syntax and extension methods syntax - see update